# Symfony .htaccess to redirect in public/index.php

Tags: php, symfony, .htaccess

Hello I have a problem with my .htaccess at the root of the Symfony project during deployment.

Currently working on a Symfony 6 project I had a problem displaying assets so now I've fixed it.
But another problem comes when I redirect myself to my domain name https://www.example.com, the url is automatically redirected to:

```
https://www.example.com/public
```

So I need help I don't understand the .htaccess files from the root of the project which would have redirected the .htaccess which is in public created by apache.

Here is my .htaccess file at the root of the project:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Here is my .htaccess file which is in public:

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options +FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/index" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/index.php" but be rewritten to "/index.php/index".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # This Option needs to be enabled for RewriteRule, otherwise it will show an error like
    # 'Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden'
    Options +FollowSymlinks

    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/index.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Thanks if anyone has an answer I would be really grateful.

Comment: You don't need any of this if you just fix your virtual host and make it use `public` as `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

Comment: Redirecting to a folder named `public` sounds strange - does the docroot point to the application root, such that **al**l folders would be accesible?

Answer (score 1):

Your document root is incorrect. From [Configuring a Web Server](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#adding-rewrite-rules-for-apache) documentation:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # ...
    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public

    <Directory /var/www/project/public>
        AllowOverride None

        # Copy .htaccess contents here
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I don't understand the VirtualHost, you can tell me where I can find it. I am using windows 10 with wampserver installer. please tell me in which folder and file i can find the VirtualHost.
I am using Symfony 6.3.1.

Comment: I've no idea of where your third-party bundle can possibly put stuff. I found [this tutorial](https://techdirectarchive.com/2023/04/26/how-to-create-virtual-hosts-in-a-wampserver/) in Google.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try to  write a route in Symfony to force a redirect from "/public" to the main domain,
Some like

```
redirect_public_to_home:
    path: /public
    controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::redirectPublicToHome
```

This route definition specifies that when a request is made to "/public", it should be handled by the redirectPublicToHome action in the DefaultController class.

Now Create the DefaultController class if it doesn't exist already. In the example, it is assumed that the controller is located at src/Controller/DefaultController.php. Add the following code to the class:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class DefaultController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/public", name="redirect_public_to_home")
     */
    public function redirectPublicToHome(): RedirectResponse
    {
        return new RedirectResponse('/', RedirectResponse::HTTP_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
    }
}
```

This code defines the redirectPublicToHome action, which returns a redirect response to the root URL ("/") with a status code of 301 (Moved Permanently).

Make sure that the routing configuration file and the DefaultController namespace and file paths match the conventions used in your Symfony project

Answer (score -2):

Based on the provided .htaccess files, it seems that your Symfony project is not configured properly to serve the application directly from the root of your domain.

To fix this issue and remove the "/public" part from the URL, you need to make the following changes:

.htaccess file at the root of your project

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess file in the "public" directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # ... Existing rules

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    # ... Existing rules
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried what you told me and still nothing